# Как создать ещё одну папку в сборке create-react-app?

Tags: php, reactjs, create-react-app

Всем привет! У меня есть проект на React JS и PHP, где есть отдельная папка с картинками uploads. В эту папку я загружаю картинки с помощью PHP. Как мне сделать так, чтобы после сборки всего проекта, помимо основных папок (js, css, media), создавалась ещё одна папка uploads, в которой будут те самые картинки? В какую сторону копать? Кто сталкивался с этим, помогите пожалуйста :) Использую create-react-app

Comment: create-react-app создаёт frontend часть вашего приложения, и в неё лучше ни пихать серверную часть. Поместите это папку куда-либо ещё.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov В плане? Куда поместить?

Comment: Frontend посылает картинки на сервер, который сам решает куда ему их поместить. Сборка frontend проекта не должна смешиваться с серверной частью. Создайте отдельную папку вне frontend проекта и скажите PHP туда сохранять приходящие изображения.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Я сделал как вы сказали. Как теперь объяснить реакту, что изображения нужно брать из той папки? React у меня сейчас берёт изображения через require из папки uploads, но при сборки всё равно всё переносится в media. Может require на что-нибудь другое можно заменить?

Comment: Смотрите ответ на англоязычном [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477692/create-react-app-where-do-i-put-dynamically-uploaded-images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решил следующим способом:**

Кто столкнулся с такой же проблемой как у меня, то вам на помощь придут сервисы для загрузки изображений, такие как imgur, imgbb, postimg и т.д., их полно. На таких сайтах как правило есть API и любой программист может им воспользоваться. Лично я воспользовался imgbb. Просто по url отправляете изображение и получаете ссылку на неё. Всем удачи с решением!)))